# How to combine the letters in two strings in haskell

Tags: string, haskell, char, list-comprehension

I am learning Haskell and following the guide on http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out. I am at the point where it is shown:

```
ghci> let nouns = ["hobo","frog","pope"]  
ghci> let adjectives = ["lazy","grouchy","scheming"]  
ghci> [adjective ++ " " ++ noun | adjective <- adjectives, noun <- nouns]  
["lazy hobo","lazy frog","lazy pope","grouchy hobo","grouchy frog",  
"grouchy pope","scheming hobo","scheming frog","scheming pope"]
```

What I'd like to achieve, it is something similar, but combining the letters contained in two strings, and since strings are basically lists of char in Haskell, this is what I tried:

```
 [x ++ ' ' ++ y | x <- "ab", y <- "cd"]
```

But the compiler is complaining:

```
Prelude> [y ++ ' ' ++ y | x <- "abd", y <- "bcd"]

<interactive>:50:2:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Char’
    Relevant bindings include it :: [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:50:1)
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘y’
    In the expression: y ++ ' ' ++ y

<interactive>:50:7:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Char’
    Relevant bindings include it :: [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:50:1)
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘' '’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘' ' ++ y’
    In the expression: y ++ ' ' ++ y

<interactive>:50:14:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Char’
    Relevant bindings include it :: [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:50:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘y’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘' ' ++ y’
```

I did a number of tries, such as wrapping the expression in brackets to get a list, changed the space to be a String rather than a char... How can I get it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`++` works only for lists, but `x` and `y` are only `Char`. After all, they're elements from a `String` (= `[Char]`), whereas the LYAH example had lists of lists of `Char`: `[String] = [[Char]]`:

```
-- [a] -> [a] -> [a]
-- vv     vv
[y ++ ' ' ++ y | x <- "abd", y <- "bcd"]
--           ^   ^           ^
--           Char           Char

-- vs

--                                        [String]          [String]
--                                       vvvvvvvvvv          vvvvv
[adjective ++ " " ++ noun | adjective <- adjectives, noun <- nouns]  
-- ^^^^^^^           ^^^^
-- String           String
```

Instead, use `(:)` to cons the characters on each other and onto the empty list:

```
[x : ' ' : y : [] | x <- "abd", y <- "bcd"]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
x ++ ' ' ++ y
```

The actual problem here is, you are trying to concatenate three characters, with a function defined only for list of items.
[`++`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) will actually concatenate two lists, not two individual items and give a list.

1. So, you can fix your program either by converting all the characters to strings, like this

   ```
   > [[x] ++ " " ++ [y] | x <- "ab", y <- "cd"]
   ["a c","a d","b c","b d"]
   ```

   Note the `" "`, not `' '`. Because `" "` means a string with just a space character, but `' '` means just the space character.
2. Or, convert `y` to a String, use `cons` operator with the `' '`, and concatenate it to `x` converted to a string, like this

   ```
   > [[x] ++ (' ' : [y]) | x <- "ab", y <- "cd"]
   ["a c","a d","b c","b d"]
   ```
3. Or, even simpler and intutive, [as suggested by chi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513264/how-to-combine-the-letters-in-two-strings-in-haskell/28513411#comment45348214_28513411), create a list of characters, like this

   ```
   > [[x, ' ', y] | x <- "ab", y <- "cd"]
   ["a c","a d","b c","b d"]
   ```

**Note:** Wrapping a character with `[]` makes it a list of characters with just one character in it. It basically becomes a String.

Comment: I find `[x,' ',y]` visually nice here.